# geom_point how to assign value from two different dataset with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I'm trying plot point from two different data set in one graph. I wanna add the "value" of the points with `geom_text` but this is not working.

I can not show you the data set, but both dataset `p1` and `p2` have 3 column which are number.

I wanna plot column 3 function of column 2 (points from `p2` in **red** points from `p1` in **blue**), and add column 1 as label

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(size = 8, col = "red", aes(x = p2[, 3], y = p2[, 2] / sum(p2[, 2]))) +
  geom_text(label = p2[, 1]) + 
  ylab("frequence") +  
  geom_point(size = 8, col = "blue", aes(x = p1[, 3], y = p1[, 2] / sum(p1[, 2]))) +
  geom_text(label = p1[, 1])
```

Plot me the points I want in respectivly blue and red but there is no labels.

I can print the label from 2 data set with

```
ggplot(p2, aes(x = p2[, 3], y = p2[, 2] / sum(p2[, 2]))) + 
  geom_text(label = p2[, 1]) + 
  ylab("frequence") + 
  geom_point(size = 8, col = "red", alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_point(size = 8, col = "blue", alpha = 0.2, aes(x = p1[, 3], y = p1[, 2] / sum(p1[, 2]))) + 
  geom_text(label = p1[, 1])
```

The problem here is that both label are printed in my red point

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

As you are using 2 datasets, you should specify within each `geom function` the right datasets, with the parameter `data =` .

```
library(ggplot)

p1 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(10), c2 = rnorm(10), c3 = rnorm(10))
p2 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(10), c2 = rnorm(10), c3 = rnorm(10))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = c3, y = c2 / sum(c2)), col = "red", data = p2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = c3, y = c2 / sum(c2), label = round(c1, 2)), data = p2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = c3, y = c2 / sum(c2)), col = "blue", data = p1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = c3, y = c2 / sum(c2), label = round(c1, 2)), data = p1)
```

[image]